# How do I activate the check-in feature for my Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook-pages, geolocation

I manage a Fan Page for a hotel in Dubai.  My client's address is not being recognized by Facebook as we currently do not use postal codes here.

Is there a way to activate the "check in" mechanism without this?

Answer (score 1):

When creating the Page, you should have chosen the `Local Business or Place` category.

If this was not done originally, then it can be fixed after-the-fact using:

`Edit Page` ==> `Update Public Info` ==> `Basic Information`:

change `Category:` to `Local Businesses`.